# Deploy Play 2.2.1 to Heroku

Tags: heroku, playframework

I'm not able to deploy a Play 2.2.1 app to heroku. Here is what I see:

```
Delta compression using up to 4 threads.
Compressing objects: 100% (1056/1056), done.
Writing objects: 100% (1163/1163), 271.55 KiB | 136 KiB/s, done.
Total 1163 (delta 565), reused 0 (delta 0)

-----> Removing .DS_Store files
-----> Fetching custom git buildpack... done

 !     Push rejected, no Cedar-supported app detected

To git@heroku.com:pacific-chamber-5618.git
 ! [remote rejected] master -> master (pre-receive hook declined)
error: failed to push some refs to 'git@heroku.com:pacific-chamber-5618.git
```

Any reasons as to why this should fail?

Comment: What buildpack are you using?

Comment: Do you have an app in the folder or did you just initialize a folder and pushed it?

Comment: I used the scala build pack but still the same result.

Comment: Which folder do you mean?

Comment: What files do you have in your git repo?  I think the scala buildpack looks for a `project/build.properties` file.

Comment: Yes, I do have a build.properties file inside the project folder. I'm confused as to why that would not be respected.